# Docker-machine ssh displays junk characters on windows 7

Tags: windows-7-x64, docker-machine

I have installed docker-machine on 64 bit Windows 7 machine. It also installed Oracle Virtual Box to which docker-machine connects to. The issue is that it is getting very difficult to work on docker-machine. Reason is ssh-ing to virtual machine displays a lot of junk characters. Below is what I get when I just vi newfile. Similar junk characters on cat existingfile. Or if I click on backspace to delete any character on command prompt.

[image: Docker machine junk character on vi newfile]

[image: Docker machine version on windows 7 64 bit]

[image: Oracle Virtual Box version]

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same issue. I came across [this](https://getcarina.com/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-cannot-enable-tty-mode-on-windows/) page during my search which prompted me to try using bash.

Install git if you do not already have it. You can then run the following command from PowerShell to drop into a bash shell (assuming default location for git).

```
& "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe"
```

I have created the alias 'bash' for this in my PowerShell profile folder, which you can find from [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176913.aspx).

```
New-Alias bash "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe"
```

Now drop into a bash shell first before using docker-machine ssh and there should be no more junk characters.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Do you know how to make docker available within the bash? Thank you.

Comment: @andNoob Go to the installation folder of docker, where the file docker-machine.exe is located, so you can use the command

Comment: @andNoob maybe better late then never... You can add the docker installation dir to your windows "path" environment variable as well.